# Store Video on Azure Cloud

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I want to develop website(asp.net mvc)  for store and retrieve video file from azure cloud.Can anyone push me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Azure Storage Facility, provides you with Azure Blob Storage which is used for saving large binary files.

Following is a link to the documentation center
[Documentation Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/)

For sample code, install Azure SDK and go to 
"Visual Studio C# -> Cloud -> QuickStarts -> Azure Storage: Blobs" in Visual Studio 15
Provides a set of basic task and ready code to play with.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at various Azure services offered on azure.com?

To host your MVC app, one option is to use Web Apps.

To store and retrieve your video file, one option is to use Blob storage.  Another option is to use Media Services.